# agent population produces error after inserting parameters loaded from database

Tags: anylogic

I would like to load my trucks on specific docks like loading truck A on dock 50. After I insert population loaded from database  I get the error that it doesn't find my storages and it cant't calculate the space of my palletracks/ docks. Could it be that whenever I insert a population via database that the program ignore the other parameters of the agent like my storage? Before I insert the database, it works fine.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNEnq.png)

[populationloadDocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4evAt.png)

[resourcepool_dockloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEiy4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to load all parameters from the dbase table in the properties of your agent population under "Agent parameter mapping" (visible in your second screenshot).

The AnyLogic help explains more on how this works but you essentially tell your agents which parameters should be filled from which table column.

Comment: Benjamin, i can't add parameters like nodes into a dbase table.

Comment: true. You can only store characteristics about your nodes (position, etc.) and then create them at runtime. Not sure what this has to do with your problem. You must use my solution to get further. If you are stuck, you will need to ask about your new problem from scratch :-)

Comment: Yes I know what you mean but the id is the only parameter for the dbase which i use in the agent dock. The others like timearrival is part of the population loadingtrucks :) the other parameter which are in the agent dock are listed like the different nodes and the storage. the storage has the type PalletRack.But I couldn't use this parameters in the dbase like you said too

Comment: Sorry, but can you distill your current problem into a clean, new question? (SOF is not a place for lengthy discussion threads but a Q&A so let's keep things clean :) ).